# How can I rotate a 2D shape with respect to another?

Tags: plotting, graphics, linear-algebra, data

```
shap1 = {{-(\[Pi]/3), -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}, {-((2 \[Pi])/3), 
    0}, {-(\[Pi]/3), \[Pi]/Sqrt[3]}, {\[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/
     Sqrt[3]}, {(2 \[Pi])/3, 
    0}, {\[Pi]/3, -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}, {\[Pi]/
     3, -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}, {-(\[Pi]/3), -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}};

shap2 = {{-0.9087705590023273`, -1.123217286137945`}, \
{-1.4354874266116266`, 0.16388059320255716`}, {-0.6322248754914552`, 
    1.2991430666398163`}, {0.908770559002327`, 
    1.123217286137945`}, {1.4354874266116266`, -0.1638805932025569`}, \
{0.6322248754914549`, -1.2991430666398165`}, {0.6322248754914549`, \
-1.2991430666398165`}, {-0.9087705590023273`, -1.123217286137945`}};

ListLinePlot[{shap1, shap2}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I  would like to rotate the red one to be horizontal like the black one and then get the new coordinate of the corner points after rotation.

So, first, I calculate the angle of rotation as follows

```
rotangl=VectorAngle[{1,0}, {1, (shap2[[3]][[2]] - shap2[[4]][[2]])/2}];
```

Finally, I rotate the shape (green)

```
ListLinePlot[{shap1, shap2, RotationMatrix[rotangl] . # & /@ shap2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Green}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

But did not work, it is not exactly horizental, any help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?
Rotate the vector `shap2[[3]] - shap2[[4]]`  according to `shap1[[3]] - shap1[[4]]`.

```
m = RotationMatrix[{shap1[[3]] - shap1[[4]], shap2[[3]] - shap2[[4]]}];
ListLinePlot[{shap1, shap2 . m}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

another option

[image]

```
shap1 = {{-(\[Pi]/3), -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}, {-((2 \[Pi])/3), 
    0}, {-(\[Pi]/3), \[Pi]/Sqrt[3]}, {\[Pi]/3, \[Pi]/
     Sqrt[3]}, {(2 \[Pi])/3, 
    0}, {\[Pi]/3, -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}, {\[Pi]/
     3, -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}, {-(\[Pi]/3), -(\[Pi]/Sqrt[3])}};

shap2 = {{-0.9087705590023273`, -1.123217286137945`}, 
{-1.4354874266116266`, 0.16388059320255716`}, {-0.6322248754914552`, 
    1.2991430666398163`}, {0.908770559002327`, 
    1.123217286137945`}, {1.4354874266116266`, -0.1638805932025569`}, 
{0.6322248754914549`, -1.2991430666398165`}, {0.6322248754914549`, 
-1.2991430666398165`}, {-0.9087705590023273`, -1.123217286137945`}};

Manipulate[
 Module[{r, v},
  r = RotationTransform[theta0 Degree];
  v = r[shap2];
  Grid[{{v},
    {ListLinePlot[{shap1, v}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
      PlotMarkers -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 300, 
      GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]}
    }]
  ]
 ,
 {{theta0, 0, "angle"}, 0, 360, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {theta0}
 ]
```

The updated coordinates could also be shown on the points on the graph if needed.

Answer (score 4):

`shap1` and `shap2` are list of points (not regions) so let's extract the furthest x coordinates from both.

```
v1 = SortBy[shap1, First][[{1, -1}]] // N
v2 = SortBy[shap2, First][[{1, -1}]]

Graphics[{ 
  Black, Line@shap1
  , Red, Line@shap2
  , AbsolutePointSize[6]
  , Darker@Green
  , Point /@ v1
  , Point /@ v2
  }
 , Axes -> True
 ]
```

So far,

[image]

Extract angle:

```
rotArg = PlanarAngle[{0, 0} -> {Last@v2, Last@v1}]
```

> 0.113672

```
shap3 = RotationTransform[rotArg]@shap2 // Chop
```

> ```
> {{-0.775503, -1.21905}, {-1.44481, 0}, {-0.775503, 
>   1.21905}, {0.775503, 1.21905}, {1.44481, 
>   0}, {0.775503, -1.21905}, {0.775503, -1.21905}, {-0.775503, \
> -1.21905}}
> ```

```
ListLinePlot[{shap1, shap2, shap3}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Darker@Green}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]